# How to implement md5 on string without using "using System.Security.Cryptography;" or any other built in methods - C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, md5

I am trying to implement md5 encryption on a string but cannot find any example of a working algorithm. I did research but couldn't find any thing on the net other than tutorials explaining the algorithm
Or is there anyway i can the code in the built in classes

Comment: you do realize the .net framework is open source right?  search git

Comment: then you can compile the the code from source yourself - good luck!

Comment: What's wrong with built-in implementations?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/cryptoapi.cs,c6f8abff273feb70

Comment: I know it's not free, but I highly recommend using ReSharper. Not only does it provide a lot of productivity functionality but it also comes with a simple decompiler allowing you to look at the classes and implementations without having to go search for them on the git repos or on referencesource.microsoft.com

Comment: rather than links does anyone actually know what steps to do to implement the algo . as mentioned before i checked the net and git also but i cant find an implementation without built in methods. The reason i am not using built in methods is so that i can understand what to do and how to do .

Comment: [My response to this question](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/022/978/yNlQWRM.jpg). _"rather than links does anyone actually know what steps to do to implement the algo"_ - John literally linked you to Microsoft's implementation. Otherwise, [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) has pseudocode.

Comment: Remember, many legitimate questions are just not well-suited to stackoverflow. Tutorial-type questions are an example, as are very open-ended questions (too broad). MD5 is a complex algorithm with many steps, so you'd need to be much more specific in what part(s) you need help with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the implementation:

```
public class MD5
{
    /***********************VARIABLES************************************/


    /***********************Statics**************************************/
    /// <summary>
    /// lookup table 4294967296*sin(i)
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly static uint []  T =new uint[64] 
        {   0xd76aa478,0xe8c7b756,0x242070db,0xc1bdceee,
            0xf57c0faf,0x4787c62a,0xa8304613,0xfd469501,
            0x698098d8,0x8b44f7af,0xffff5bb1,0x895cd7be,
            0x6b901122,0xfd987193,0xa679438e,0x49b40821,
            0xf61e2562,0xc040b340,0x265e5a51,0xe9b6c7aa,
            0xd62f105d,0x2441453,0xd8a1e681,0xe7d3fbc8,
            0x21e1cde6,0xc33707d6,0xf4d50d87,0x455a14ed,
            0xa9e3e905,0xfcefa3f8,0x676f02d9,0x8d2a4c8a,
            0xfffa3942,0x8771f681,0x6d9d6122,0xfde5380c,
            0xa4beea44,0x4bdecfa9,0xf6bb4b60,0xbebfbc70,
            0x289b7ec6,0xeaa127fa,0xd4ef3085,0x4881d05,
            0xd9d4d039,0xe6db99e5,0x1fa27cf8,0xc4ac5665,
            0xf4292244,0x432aff97,0xab9423a7,0xfc93a039,
            0x655b59c3,0x8f0ccc92,0xffeff47d,0x85845dd1,
            0x6fa87e4f,0xfe2ce6e0,0xa3014314,0x4e0811a1,
            0xf7537e82,0xbd3af235,0x2ad7d2bb,0xeb86d391};

    /*****instance variables**************/
    /// <summary>
    /// X used to proces data in 
    /// 512 bits chunks as 16 32 bit word
    /// </summary>
    protected  uint [] X = new uint [16];   

    /// <summary>
    /// the finger print obtained. 
    /// </summary>
    protected Digest dgFingerPrint;         

    /// <summary>
    /// the input bytes
    /// </summary>
    protected   byte [] m_byteInput;        



    /**********************EVENTS AND DELEGATES*******************************************/

    public delegate void ValueChanging (object sender,MD5ChangingEventArgs Changing);
    public delegate void ValueChanged (object sender,MD5ChangedEventArgs Changed);


    public event ValueChanging OnValueChanging;
    public event ValueChanged  OnValueChanged;



    /********************************************************************/
    /***********************PROPERTIES ***********************/
    /// <summary>
    ///gets or sets as string
    /// </summary>
    public string Value
    {
        get
        { 
            string st ;
            char [] tempCharArray= new Char[m_byteInput.Length];

            for(int i =0; i<m_byteInput.Length;i++)
                tempCharArray[i]=(char)m_byteInput[i];

            st= new String(tempCharArray);
            return st;
        }
        set
        {
            /// raise the event to notify the changing 
            if (this.OnValueChanging !=null)
                this.OnValueChanging(this,new MD5ChangingEventArgs(value));


            m_byteInput=new byte[value.Length];
            for (int i =0; i<value.Length;i++)
                m_byteInput[i]=(byte)value[i];
            dgFingerPrint=CalculateMD5Value();              

            /// raise the event to notify the change
            if (this.OnValueChanged !=null)
                this.OnValueChanged(this,new MD5ChangedEventArgs(value,dgFingerPrint.ToString()));

        }
    }       

    /// <summary>
    /// get/sets as  byte array 
    /// </summary>
    public byte [] ValueAsByte
    {
        get
        {
            byte [] bt = new byte[m_byteInput.Length];
            for (int i =0; i<m_byteInput.Length;i++)
                bt[i]=m_byteInput[i];
            return bt;
      }
        set
        {
            /// raise the event to notify the changing
            if (this.OnValueChanging !=null)
                this.OnValueChanging(this,new MD5ChangingEventArgs(value));

            m_byteInput=new byte[value.Length];
            for (int i =0; i<value.Length;i++)
                m_byteInput[i]=value[i];
            dgFingerPrint=CalculateMD5Value();


            /// notify the changed  value
            if (this.OnValueChanged !=null)
                this.OnValueChanged(this,new MD5ChangedEventArgs(value,dgFingerPrint.ToString()));
        }
    }

    //gets the signature/figner print as string
    public  string FingerPrint
    {
        get
        {
            return dgFingerPrint.ToString();
        }
    }


    /*************************************************************************/
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MD5()
    {           
        Value="";
    }


    /******************************************************************************/
    /*********************METHODS**************************/

    /// <summary>
    /// calculat md5 signature of the string in Input
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> Digest: the finger print of msg</returns>
    protected Digest CalculateMD5Value()
    {
        /***********vairable declaration**************/
        byte [] bMsg;   //buffer to hold bits
        uint N;         //N is the size of msg as  word (32 bit) 
        Digest dg =new Digest();            //  the value to be returned

        // create a buffer with bits padded and length is alos padded
        bMsg=CreatePaddedBuffer();

        N=(uint)(bMsg.Length*8)/32;     //no of 32 bit blocks

        for (uint  i=0; i<N/16;i++)
        {
            CopyBlock(bMsg,i);
            PerformTransformation(ref dg.A,ref dg.B,ref dg.C,ref dg.D);
        }
        return dg;
    }

    /********************************************************
     * TRANSFORMATIONS :  FF , GG , HH , II  acc to RFC 1321
     * where each Each letter represnets the aux function used
     *********************************************************/



    /// <summary>
    /// perform transformatio using f(((b&c) | (~(b)&d))
    /// </summary>
    protected void TransF(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d,uint k,ushort s, uint i )
    {
        a = b + MD5Helper.RotateLeft((a + ((b&c) | (~(b)&d)) + X[k] + T[i-1]), s);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// perform transformatio using g((b&d) | (c & ~d) )
    /// </summary>
    protected void TransG(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d,uint k,ushort s, uint i )
    {
        a = b + MD5Helper.RotateLeft((a + ((b&d) | (c & ~d) ) + X[k] + T[i-1]), s);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// perform transformatio using h(b^c^d)
    /// </summary>
    protected void TransH(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d,uint k,ushort s, uint i )
    {
        a = b + MD5Helper.RotateLeft((a + (b^c^d) + X[k] + T[i-1]), s);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// perform transformatio using i (c^(b|~d))
    /// </summary>
    protected void TransI(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d,uint k,ushort s, uint i )
    {
        a = b + MD5Helper.RotateLeft((a + (c^(b|~d))+ X[k] + T[i-1]), s);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Perform All the transformation on the data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="A">A</param>
    /// <param name="B">B </param>
    /// <param name="C">C</param>
    /// <param name="D">D</param>
    protected void PerformTransformation(ref uint A,ref uint B,ref uint C, ref uint D)
    {
        //// saving  ABCD  to be used in end of loop

        uint AA,BB,CC,DD;

        AA=A;   
        BB=B;
        CC=C;
        DD=D;

        /* Round 1 
            * [ABCD  0  7  1]  [DABC  1 12  2]  [CDAB  2 17  3]  [BCDA  3 22  4]
            * [ABCD  4  7  5]  [DABC  5 12  6]  [CDAB  6 17  7]  [BCDA  7 22  8]
            * [ABCD  8  7  9]  [DABC  9 12 10]  [CDAB 10 17 11]  [BCDA 11 22 12]
            * [ABCD 12  7 13]  [DABC 13 12 14]  [CDAB 14 17 15]  [BCDA 15 22 16]
            *  * */
        TransF(ref A,B,C,D,0,7,1);TransF(ref D,A,B,C,1,12,2);TransF(ref C,D,A,B,2,17,3);TransF(ref B,C,D,A,3,22,4);
        TransF(ref A,B,C,D,4,7,5);TransF(ref D,A,B,C,5,12,6);TransF(ref C,D,A,B,6,17,7);TransF(ref B,C,D,A,7,22,8);
        TransF(ref A,B,C,D,8,7,9);TransF(ref D,A,B,C,9,12,10);TransF(ref C,D,A,B,10,17,11);TransF(ref B,C,D,A,11,22,12);
        TransF(ref A,B,C,D,12,7,13);TransF(ref D,A,B,C,13,12,14);TransF(ref C,D,A,B,14,17,15);TransF(ref B,C,D,A,15,22,16);
        /** rOUND 2
            **[ABCD  1  5 17]  [DABC  6  9 18]  [CDAB 11 14 19]  [BCDA  0 20 20]
            *[ABCD  5  5 21]  [DABC 10  9 22]  [CDAB 15 14 23]  [BCDA  4 20 24]
            *[ABCD  9  5 25]  [DABC 14  9 26]  [CDAB  3 14 27]  [BCDA  8 20 28]
            *[ABCD 13  5 29]  [DABC  2  9 30]  [CDAB  7 14 31]  [BCDA 12 20 32]
        */
        TransG(ref A,B,C,D,1,5,17);TransG(ref D,A,B,C,6,9,18);TransG(ref C,D,A,B,11,14,19);TransG(ref B,C,D,A,0,20,20);
        TransG(ref A,B,C,D,5,5,21);TransG(ref D,A,B,C,10,9,22);TransG(ref C,D,A,B,15,14,23);TransG(ref B,C,D,A,4,20,24);
        TransG(ref A,B,C,D,9,5,25);TransG(ref D,A,B,C,14,9,26);TransG(ref C,D,A,B,3,14,27);TransG(ref B,C,D,A,8,20,28);
        TransG(ref A,B,C,D,13,5,29);TransG(ref D,A,B,C,2,9,30);TransG(ref C,D,A,B,7,14,31);TransG(ref B,C,D,A,12,20,32);
        /*  rOUND 3
            * [ABCD  5  4 33]  [DABC  8 11 34]  [CDAB 11 16 35]  [BCDA 14 23 36]
            * [ABCD  1  4 37]  [DABC  4 11 38]  [CDAB  7 16 39]  [BCDA 10 23 40]
            * [ABCD 13  4 41]  [DABC  0 11 42]  [CDAB  3 16 43]  [BCDA  6 23 44]
            * [ABCD  9  4 45]  [DABC 12 11 46]  [CDAB 15 16 47]  [BCDA  2 23 48]
         * */
        TransH(ref A,B,C,D,5,4,33);TransH(ref D,A,B,C,8,11,34);TransH(ref C,D,A,B,11,16,35);TransH(ref B,C,D,A,14,23,36);
        TransH(ref A,B,C,D,1,4,37);TransH(ref D,A,B,C,4,11,38);TransH(ref C,D,A,B,7,16,39);TransH(ref B,C,D,A,10,23,40);
        TransH(ref A,B,C,D,13,4,41);TransH(ref D,A,B,C,0,11,42);TransH(ref C,D,A,B,3,16,43);TransH(ref B,C,D,A,6,23,44);
        TransH(ref A,B,C,D,9,4,45);TransH(ref D,A,B,C,12,11,46);TransH(ref C,D,A,B,15,16,47);TransH(ref B,C,D,A,2,23,48);
        /*ORUNF  4
            *[ABCD  0  6 49]  [DABC  7 10 50]  [CDAB 14 15 51]  [BCDA  5 21 52]
            *[ABCD 12  6 53]  [DABC  3 10 54]  [CDAB 10 15 55]  [BCDA  1 21 56]
            *[ABCD  8  6 57]  [DABC 15 10 58]  [CDAB  6 15 59]  [BCDA 13 21 60]
            *[ABCD  4  6 61]  [DABC 11 10 62]  [CDAB  2 15 63]  [BCDA  9 21 64]
                     * */
        TransI(ref A,B,C,D,0,6,49);TransI(ref D,A,B,C,7,10,50);TransI(ref C,D,A,B,14,15,51);TransI(ref B,C,D,A,5,21,52);
        TransI(ref A,B,C,D,12,6,53);TransI(ref D,A,B,C,3,10,54);TransI(ref C,D,A,B,10,15,55);TransI(ref B,C,D,A,1,21,56);
        TransI(ref A,B,C,D,8,6,57);TransI(ref D,A,B,C,15,10,58);TransI(ref C,D,A,B,6,15,59);TransI(ref B,C,D,A,13,21,60);
        TransI(ref A,B,C,D,4,6,61);TransI(ref D,A,B,C,11,10,62);TransI(ref C,D,A,B,2,15,63);TransI(ref B,C,D,A,9,21,64);


        A=A+AA;
        B=B+BB;
        C=C+CC;
        D=D+DD;


    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Create Padded buffer for processing , buffer is padded with 0 along 
    /// with the size in the end
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>the padded buffer as byte array</returns>
    protected byte[] CreatePaddedBuffer()
    {
        uint pad;       //no of padding bits for 448 mod 512 
        byte [] bMsg;   //buffer to hold bits
        ulong sizeMsg;      //64 bit size pad
        uint sizeMsgBuff;   //buffer size in multiple of bytes
        int temp=(448-((m_byteInput.Length*8)%512)); //temporary 


        pad = (uint )((temp+512)%512);      //getting no of bits to  be pad
        if (pad==0)             ///pad is in bits
            pad=512;            //at least 1 or max 512 can be added

        sizeMsgBuff= (uint) ((m_byteInput.Length)+ (pad/8)+8);
        sizeMsg=(ulong)m_byteInput.Length*8;
        bMsg=new byte[sizeMsgBuff]; ///no need to pad with 0 coz new bytes 
        // are already initialize to 0 :)




        ////copying string to buffer 
        for (int i =0; i<m_byteInput.Length;i++)
            bMsg[i]=m_byteInput[i];

        bMsg[m_byteInput.Length]|=0x80;     ///making first bit of padding 1,

        //wrting the size value
        for (int i =8; i >0;i--)
            bMsg[sizeMsgBuff-i]=(byte) (sizeMsg>>((8-i)*8) & 0x00000000000000ff);

        return bMsg;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Copies a 512 bit block into X as 16 32 bit words
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bMsg"> source buffer</param>
    /// <param name="block">no of block to copy starting from 0</param>
    protected void CopyBlock(byte[] bMsg,uint block)
    {

        block=block<<6;
        for (uint j=0; j<61;j+=4)
        {
            X[j>>2]=(((uint) bMsg[block+(j+3)]) <<24 ) |
                    (((uint) bMsg[block+(j+2)]) <<16 ) |
                    (((uint) bMsg[block+(j+1)]) <<8 ) |
                    (((uint) bMsg[block+(j)]) ) ;

        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/MD5/Implementation#C.23

Comment: i've seen this but it makes no sense to a beginner like me. Could u explain the steps . Like for example i entered a string what do i do step by step to it? for the 512 bit block do i need to convert the string to hexadecimal or something?

Comment: We cant write a post to teach your about all the ways to understand cryptography, actually we don't even by nature tell you how to do things that are subjective and opinionated. We do however solve concrete problems with concrete answers... Please take this time to read [help/on-topic]

Comment: @Khwaja Modern cryptography is not typically as simple as "take a string and move the characters around", or "if it's an A replace it with an N" - certainly not when it comes to hashing algorithms. If you don't understand it, I'm afraid that it's not our place to answer. I would argue that you don't need to understand it to use it.

Comment: @KhwajaHussamQuasmi to fully understand how it works, I would suggest to read a book about this because it's hard to explain in a comment.

Comment: but the answer is not complete, it uses class and helpers that are not included here, the  source link links to other website that has full source available to download but is down :(